# Dynamic active menu items Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have created a template tag for return active or nothing to every menu item, if I hardcode every url , it will work, like here:

```
 <li class="{% active request '^/danmark/$' %}"><a href="/danmark/"> Hele Danmark</a>
```

But if i use dymanic url, there wont be add any active class  to any menu item, if the the url is `^/danmark/{{a.area}}/$`, like here:

```
 {% for a in all_areas %}
        <li class="{% active request '^/danmark/{{a.area}}/$' %} "><a href= "/danmark/{{a.area}}/">{{a.area}} </a></li>     
    {% endfor %}
```

and template tag:

from django import template
register = template.Library()

```
@register.simple_tag
def active(request, pattern):
   import re
   if re.search(pattern, request.path):
      return 'active'
   return ''
```

What can I do here?

Comment: Your class is also dependent of area? if not then you set your class as `class="{% active request '^/danmark/$' %} "`

Comment: yes it is also depend on areas.

Comment: Can you show the template tag function?

Comment: just add my template tag, it work fine when I hardcode url .

Comment: use activelink. works out of the box. https://github.com/j4mie/django-activelink

Comment: django-activelink doesn't work in this case

Answer (score 6):

You can try this

```
{% with request.resolver_match.url_name as url_name %}
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="{% if url_name == 'home' %}active{% endif %}">Home</li>
    <li class="{% if url_name == 'about' %}active{% endif %}">About</li>
    <li class="{% if url_name == 'employer' %}active{% endif %}">Employer</li>
</ul>
 {% endwith %}
```

Where your urls are like

```
url(r'$','home_view', name='home'),
url(r'about/$','about_view', name='about'),
url(r'employer/$','employer_view', name='employer')
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't put some signal in your view like:

```
active = 'danmark'
```

then in temlate you can do:

```
<li{% if active=='danmark' %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="/danmark/"> Hele Danmark</a></li>
```